# Socket.io - Prevent multiple events from firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket.io connection setup between my iOS app and my `nodeJS` backend.

Upon connection, I setup my socket like this:

```
    socket.on(EVENT_NAME1, params =>
        someFunc(socket, params)
    );

    socket.on(EVENT_NAME2, params =>
        someOtherFunc(socket, params)
    );

    socket.on(EVENT_NAME3, (params, callback) =>
        someThirdFunc(socket, params, callback)
    );

...
```

The problem is, sometimes my iOS app fires multiple events and I'd like to ensure on the backend, that if several of the same events arrive from one socket within `250ms` only the first one gets executed.

I created this function:

```
const timeoutEvent = (eventName, socket, params, callback, func) => {
    socket.off(eventName);
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, (params, callback) => {
                func(socket, params, callback);
            });
        } else {
            socket.on(eventName, params => {
                func(socket, params);
            });
        }
    }, 250);
};
```

which I want to use like this:

```
socket.on(EVENT_NAME3, (params, callback) => {
    timeOutEvent(EVENT_NAME3, socket, params, callback, someThirdFunc)  
    someThirdFunc(socket, params, callback);
})
```

The problem with this is that these lines won't work, as the `eventName`, `params` and `callback` are coming from the `on` function and not from the higher level `timeoutEvent` function -

```
socket.on(eventName, (params, callback) => {
    func(socket, params, callback);
});
```

How can I adjust the above code to fit this purpose?

Comment: From what I understand, consume the message. Have a flag set that once you get a message you set it to a value and it should go back to the original values after 250 ms. While the flag value is set to another value in those 250 ms, consume the message but do not do anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `connect` function, I added:

```
socket.enabled = true

socket.on(EVENT_NAME, (params, callback) => {
    socket.enabled && someFunc(socket, params, callback);
    preventMutlipleHandlers(socket);
});
```

and then I created this func:

```
const preventMutlipleHandlers = socket => {
    socket.enabled = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
        socket.enabled = true;
    }, 250);
};
```